# Querying from N:M table

Tags: sql

I have table where is

```
BookID |AuthorID
1      |1 
1      |2
3      |3
4      |4
5      |5
```

I need to query books which have more than one author.

Thank you.

Comment: Didn't you try your self? and tried to search?

Answer (score 4):

This is a basic aggregation query with a `having` clause.  You should learn the basics of the SQL query language, if you want to make use of relational databases.

```
select bookid
from table t
group by bookid
having count(*) > 1;
```